# $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} a^{-1\over x} $ for $|a|<1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, functions

I am trying to find

> $\lim_{x\rightarrow0} a^{-1\over x} $ for $|a|<1$

However, I cannot simply substitute $0$ into $-{1\over x}$

I tried considering limit approaching from the right and left side.

**Left side:**
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^-} a^{-1\over x}
\\ f(-1) = a^{1}
\\ f(-{1\over 10}) = a^{10}
\\ f(-{1\over 100}) = a^{100}$$

Since $|a| <1$, the value is approaching zero from left side.

**Right side**
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0^+} a^{-1\over x}
\\ f(1) = a^{-1}
\\ f({1\over 10}) = a^{-{10}}
\\ f({1\over 100}) = a^{-100}$$
And the value is approaching infinity

Since the limit from the left and right differ, no limit exists.

Now my question is, is there a more elegant way to do this question?

Comment: $a$ shall be positive, though, otherwise it wont be defined. Any more parameters ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that $a>0$ is a necessary condition for the expression to be defined, then use that

$$ \large a^{-1\over x}=e^{-\frac{\log a}x}$$

then consider separately the two cases $x\to0^+$ and $x\to 0^-$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $L = \lim_{x \to 0} a^{-1/x}$. Then :

$$\ln L = \ln \lim_{x \to 0} a^{-1/x} \Leftrightarrow \ln L = \lim_{x\to 0} -\frac{1}{x}\ln a$$

Now, if $a \in (0,1)$, then $-\ln a >0$.

Now, note that

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \frac{1}{x} = -\infty \quad \text{while} \quad \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{1}{x} = + \infty$$

thus the limit does not exists.

For an example, simply let $a = 1/2$. Then :

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{-1/x} = 0 \quad \text{while} \quad \lim_{x \to 0^+} \bigg(\frac{1}{2}\bigg)^{-1/x} = + \infty$$

Comment: I think you often give too much details in your solutions and it is not good for the benefit of the asker. Nevertheless very good answer of course! (+1)

Comment: @gimusi Sometimes true and sometimes not, but in this case a comment about the non-existence seemed useful ! Thanks a lot both for the input and the positive feedback though !

Comment: That's only my point of view and you must free of course totally free to answer as you like. Your answer are always very good and useful for asker! Cheers